# WPF: Textbox not firing onTextInput event

Tags: wpf, events, textbox, textinput

So basically, I have a bunch of TextBoxes that the user gets to fill out. I've got a button that I want to keep disabled until all the TextBoxes have had text entered in them. Here is a sample XAML TextBox that I'm using:

```
<TextBox Name="DelayedRecallScore" TextInput="CheckTextBoxFilled" Width="24" />
```

And here is the function that I'm trying to trigger:

```
  //Disables the OK button until all score textboxes have content
    private void CheckTextBoxFilled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        foreach (TextBox scorebox in TextBoxList)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scorebox.Text))
            {
                Ok_Button.IsEnabled = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        Ok_Button.IsEnabled = true;
         */
        MessageBox.Show("THIS MAKES NO SENSE");
    }
```

The MessageBox is not showing up when TextInput should be getting triggered. As an experiment I tried triggering CheckTextBoxFilled() on PreviewTextInput, and it worked fine then, meaning that for whatever reason, the function just isn't getting called. I also have a validation function that is triggered by PreviewTextInput, which works as it should. At first I thought PreviewTextInput might somehow be interfering with TextInput, so I took PreviewTextInput off the TextBox, but that hasn't managed to fix anything.  I'm completely befuddled by why this might happen, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happened to multicast delegates? why wouldn't it fire the user assigned event in addition to its own?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your handler for the `TextInput` event is not fired because the `TextBox` is handling the event. You could try using the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) event instead, since really you just want to know when characters were added or removed from the `TextBox`.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. I just Figured that since PreviewTextInput worked that way, there was nothing to stop TextInput from functioning the same way. TextChanged works just fine.

Comment: WPF really does like to make what should be simply tasks overly difficult.  I mean, why expose an event if it will never fire?  Ridiculous... yeah, I'm venting :D

Comment: @Ed FWIW, if you subclass TextBox, then you could handle the event. But I do see your point, though.

Comment: Yeah, there's always a workaround, and I generally like WPF, I have just been bitten so many times by what should be simple things made overly difficult by the framework on this recent project that I am getting a bit bitter.

Answer (score 8):

```
InitializeComponent();
textbox.AddHandler(TextBox.TextInputEvent, 
                   new TextCompositionEventHandler(TextBox_TextInput_1), 
                   true);
```

Comment: this does not capture a space.  the Event is not fired.

Answer (score 2):

Use "PreviewTextInput" instead, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class derived from TextBox. In the new class override the OnTextInput method. Your OnTextInput method will get called before the TextBox gets it.