# Get KeyPress character

Tags: .net, wpf, richtextbox

I just want to get the pressed char in WPF RichtTextbox.

```
Private Sub rtb_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles rtb.KeyDown
        Dim KeyConverter As New Forms.KeysConverter
        Dim S As String = KeyConverter.ConvertToString(e.Key)

    End Sub
```

But I only have keyDown event. On Keydown it becomes to be very complicated to catch the right character. Uppercase/Lowercase and special keys like "SHIFT" are fired by keydown, I first need to calculate to the pressed key. Thats complicated. 
Because WPF is less complicated in most cases, I will ask if you know any way to get the pressed key on keyboard as string or char?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `PreviewTextInput` event:

```
public Window7() {
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.richTextBox.PreviewTextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler(this.rtb_PreviewTextInput);
}

private void rtb_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
  var text = e.Text;
  var systemText = e.SystemText;
  var controlText = e.ControlText;
  var kbm = Keyboard.Modifiers;
}
```

```
Private Sub richTextBox_PreviewTextInput(sender As System.Object , e As System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs)
    Dim text As String = e.Text
    Dim controlText As String = e.ControlText
    Dim systemText As String = e.SystemText
    Dim keybm As ModifierKeys = Keyboard.Modifiers
End Sub
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also for your answer in C# AND VB :). Also for the `Keyboard.Modifiers` Info.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`TextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput.aspx) event which might help you here.

Comment: new to me. But `TextInput` event does not fire. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374710/wpf-textbox-not-firing-ontextinput-event but I wonder if you know how to get the text with TextInput.

Comment: Ok, you was on the right way. Thanks for your help. The `PreviewTextInput` solved it!