# Window textinput does not fire when typing on a textbox

Tags: wpf

On wpf, I add a textInput event for the winform: TextInput="Window_TextInput".

After typing a Textbox, the event is not fired (handled). the same if I add the TextInput for a textbox in wpf.

What did I do wrong? How can I get TextInput event fired?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374710/wpf-textbox-not-firing-ontextinput-event